# Querying associated classes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

If I have a class called Group, and in that class I have a
has_many :users

I want to add a method to the Group class to see if a specific user is in that group.  If I'm using the Devise authentication I can call the current_user.

So I guess my first question would be can I call that current_user from the model, or do I need to pass it to the method?

My second question is I should be able to do something like the following?

```
  def has_access?
    !current_user.nil && users.where(:id == current_user.id).count(:id) > 0
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call current_user in models - it's only available within the scope of controllers and views.

Which means your method's going to look a little different - perhaps try the following:

```
def has_access?(user)
  user.present? && users.where(:id => user.id).any?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

current_user is a helper so you cannot access it from a model and have to pass it as argument to the method as you said.

For your second question, Can you tell me in which class is this defined ? 
As I understand, it seems to be in the Group model definition as you are using "users" which I guess is the has_many association.
If so, the answer is obviously no since "current_user" is unknowed here.